# Como utilizar função Javascript usando FPDF

Tags: php, javascript, pdf

Pessoal tenho uma classa fdpf em php para exibir informações da compra realizada através de registro do meu banco de dados, mas não consigo executar um comando javascript para calcular e exibir os números de parcelas, valor de cada parcela e data de vencimento, eu possuo esta função funcionando em outra página perfeitamente, mas queria importa-la para o FPDF, alguem tem uma idéia? Vou posta minha classe com esta função javascript funcionando e também minha página FPDF:

Javascript funcionando - cadastro_contratos.php

```
 function calculamensalidades(){

  var valortotal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("total").value);
  var valorparcela = valortotal/document.getElementById("select_parcelas").value;
  var parcelas = parseFloat(document.getElementById("select_parcelas").value);
  var date = new Date();
  var mesvencimento = date.getMonth();
  var diavencimento = date.getDate();

  var tabela;
  tabela = "<br><table border='0' width='30%' style='text-align:center'><tr><td bgcolor='#4682B4'>Parcela</td><td bgcolor='#4682B4' >Valor</td><td bgcolor='#4682B4'>Vencimento</td></tr>";


  for(var a=0; a<document.getElementById("select_parcelas").value; a++)
 {
  var n_date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), eval(a+mesvencimento), diavencimento);
  var diavec = date.getDate();
  var mesvenc = n_date.getMonth();
  var anovenc = n_date.getFullYear();

     tabela = tabela + "<tr><td bgcolor='#9AC0CD'>"+(a+1)+"</td><td bgcolor='#9AC0CD'>R$ "+valorparcela.toFixed(2)+"</td><td bgcolor='#9AC0CD'>"+diavec+"/"+mesvenc+"/"+anovenc+"</td></tr>";
 }
 tabela=tabela+"</table>";
document.getElementById("mensalidades").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("mensalidades").innerHTML=tabela;
 }

function apagatabela(){
document.getElementById('mensalidades').innerHTML="";
}

 function liberar()
{
  var total = document.getElementById("total"); 
  var parcelas = document.getElementById("select_parcelas");

  if(total.value != "")
  {
    parcelas.disabled=false;
  }
}
```

Formulário HTML - cadastro_contratos.php:

```
<form id="adicionarformProdutos" method"post" action"" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <a href="#" id="adicionarProduto">Adicionar Produto</a>      
    <fieldset class="fieldsetProduto">
        <legend>Produto 1</legend>
        <div class="produtos">
            <label for="codProduto1">Código:</label><input class="codigoProduto" type="text" id="codProduto1" size="5" name="codProduto1" />
            <label for="nomeProduto1">Nome:</label> <input type="text" id="nomeProduto1" name="nomeProduto1" size="9"  />
            <label for="qtProduto1">Qt.:</label> <input type="text" size="1" id="qtProduto1" name="qtProduto1" onblur="calcValor()" />
            <label for="valorProduto1">Valor und. R$:</label> <input type="text" id="valorProduto1" name="valorProduto1" size="6" onkeypress="mascara(this,float)" />
        </div>
     </fieldset>
<br>
            <label>Data da Compra <input name="datacompra" type="text" id="datacompra" size="6" maxlength="10" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y')?>" onKeyUp="javascript:somente_numero(this);" onkeypress="formatar_mascara(this,'##/##/####')"/></label>
            <label>Desconto (%)<span style="display:none" id="sp_vdesconto"></span><input type="hidden"  name="vdesconto" id="vdesconto" />:<input type="text" name="desconto" size="6" value="0"id="desconto" onblur="calcValor()" /></label>   
            <label>Entrada R$<span style="display:none" id="sp_vdentrada"></span><input type="hidden" size="6" name="vdentrada" id="vdentrada" />:<input type="text" name="entrada" size="6" value="0"id="entrada" onKeyPress="return(MascaraMoeda(this,'.',',',event))" onblur="calcValor()" /></label>
<div>
  <br>
  <div>
            <label>Valor Total: <input type="text" name="total" value="0" size="6" id="total" onblur="liberar(); "/></label>
            <label>Qt. Parcelas: </label><select onchange="calculamensalidades()" disabled="disabled" value="" id="select_parcelas" name="select_parcelas">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
              <option>6</option>
            </select>
 <div id="mensalidades"></div>
</div>
<br>
    <input type="reset" onClick="apagatabela()">
    <input type="hidden" name="cadastra" value="add"  />
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $nrFicha;?>" name="cadastro" />
    <input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="Cadastrar" />  
</div><!--fechando div painelcadastro2-->
</form><!--fechando div adicionarformProdutos-->
```

Agora a classe FPDF que quero executar e exibir uma tabela parecida, sem usar o formulário HTML, pois as variáveis que vou utilizar para gerar a tabela já estão no banco de dados e sendo exibidas no FPDF abaixo:

```
<?php 
define('FPDF_FONTPATH', 'font/');
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf=new FPDF('P', 'cm', 'A4');
$pdf->Open();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);

    include"../Connections/config.php";
    $conexao = mysql_connect("$hostname_config","$username_config","$password_config")
                or die ("Erro ao realizar a conexão com o banco de dados, por favor informe o administrador do sistema (suporte@emperiumcode.com) ou envie um email para contato@buchmannoptical.com.br !");
    $db = mysql_select_db("$database_config")
                or die ("Erro ao selecionar o banco de dados, por favor informe o administrador do sistema (suporte@emperiumcode.com) ou envie um email para contato@buchmannoptical.com.br !");
    $contrato = $_GET['id'];
    $seleciona = mysql_query("SELECT contr.*,client.Snome FROM t_cadcontratos contr INNER JOIN t_cadclientes client ON contr.Ficha = client.Ficha WHERE NumContrato = '$contrato'");
      if($seleciona == ''){
        echo "Erro ao Selecionar, tente novamente !";
      }else{  
        while($res_id = mysql_fetch_array($seleciona)){
        $pdf->Cell(3,0.5,"Ficha:",0,0,'R'); $pdf->Cell(2,0.5,$res_id['Ficha'],1,1,'L');
        $pdf->Cell(3,0.5,"N Contrato:",0,0,'R'); $pdf->Cell(2,0.5,$res_id['NumContrato'],1,1,'L');
        $pdf->Cell(3,0.5,"Nome Cliente:",0,0,'R'); $pdf->Cell(5,0.5,$res_id['Snome'],1,1,'L');
        $pdf->Cell(1,0.5,"",0,1,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(0,0.5,"______________________________________________DADOS COMPRA______________________________________________",0,1,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(1,0.5,"",0,1,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(3,0.5,"Forma de Pagamento:",0,0,'R'); $pdf->Cell(5,0.5,$res_id['FormaPagamento'],0,1,'L');   
        $pdf->Cell(3,0.5,"Data Compra:",0,0,'R'); $pdf->Cell(5,0.5,date("d/m/Y", strtotime($res_id['DataContrato'])),0,0,'L');
        $pdf->Cell(3,0.5,"Parcelas:",0,0,'R'); $pdf->Cell(2,0.5,$res_id['QuantParcelas'],0,1,'L');
        $pdf->Cell(3,0.5,"Valor Compra R$:",0,0,'R'); $pdf->Cell(5,0.5,$res_id['ValorContrato'],0,0,'L');
        $pdf->Cell(3,0.5,"Produto:",0,0,'R'); $pdf->Cell(2,0.5,$res_id['DescricaoProduto'],0,1,'L');  
        $pdf->Cell(3,0.5,"Entrada R$:",0,0,'R'); $pdf->Cell(5,0.5,$res_id['Entrada'],0,0,'L');
        $pdf->Cell(3,0.5,"Vendedor:",0,0,'R'); $pdf->Cell(5,0.5,$res_id['Vendedor'],0,1,'L');
        $pdf->Cell(7.8,0.1,"--------------",0,1,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(3,0.5,"Saldo R$:",0,0,'R'); $pdf->Cell(5,0.5,$res_id['Saldo'],0,1,'L');
        $pdf->Cell(1,0.5,"",0,1,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(0,0.5,"_________________________________________________PARCELAS_________________________________________________",0,1,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(1,0.5,"",0,1,'C');
        $DataContrato = $res_id['DataContrato'];
        $QuantParcelas = $res_id['QuantParcelas'];
        $ValorContrato = $res_id['ValorContrato'];
        $Entrada = $res_id['Entrada'];
        $Saldo = $res_id['Saldo'];
        $DescricaoProduto = $res_id['DescricaoProduto'];
        $Vendedor = $res_id['Vendedor'];
        $FormaPagamento = $res_id['FormaPagamento'];
      }
    }
    $pdf->Output();
    ?>
```

Comment: Pode fazer um jsFiddle? faltam funções de javascript no código html que apresentou

Comment: ainda não usei jfFiddle @Sergio, vou tentar... Mas o que acontece é que preciso usar a mesma função de calcula mensalidade só que na classe FPDF usando para caucalo a variavel Saldo,QuantParcelas e DataContrato. Mas pelo que parcebi não consigo posta nada em javascript nesta classe...

Comment: Você não vai poder usar o mesmo JS do html, vai precisar criar um novo conforme o que é suportado pelo Adobe Reader (eu não conheço a API de JavaScript deles, mas sei que existe).

Comment: entendido, e talvez uma função php que calcula a data de vencimento através do campo de BD (dataContrato, Saldo e QuantParcelas) e exebindo no pdf por Parcela:1 - Valor parcela R$: 50,00 - data vencimento: xx/xx/xxx e exibir as demais parcelas...tens alguma ideia de como posso proceder?

Answer (score 2):

Rafael,

O Javascript que você esta utilizando é o do navegador, no momento em que ele começa a executar o arquivo pdf já foi gerado e ele não tem meios de ler ou editar os dados do arquivo.

Se as variáveis que você precisa já estão no banco o modo mais fácil seria "traduzir" a lógica das suas funções de Javascript pro PHP.

Comment: entendido, vou avaliar alguma outra lógica e trago novidades, abraços.